# Language version set to Unpublishable is not being removed from Web Database

Tags: publishing, versions

On Sitecore 8.2 nothing I am doing seems to be removing the language version of an item from the web database.

Things I have tried so far:

- Removed English version and smart published the item in English
- Removed English version and republished the item in English
- Removed English version and smart published the parent item in English
- Removed English version and republished the parent item in English

I even added the English version back and set it to unpublishable and published in all of the ways above and still nothing. Even after clearing the Sitecore cache and recycling the AppPool the version is still there. Logs do not indicate any errors occurring when publishing.

Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161221)

[image: Language Fallback In Use]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a bug in earlier Sitecore 8.2, fixed in 8.2 Update 5 (rev. 170728)

> A deleted language version of an item in the master database exists in the web database after publishing.​
>
> ​Smart Publishing does not unpublish invalid item versions.​
> See the information in the release notes:

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update5/Release%20Notes

Contact with Sitecore Support for a patch with a fix.